# ExtJS 4.1 export grid store to PDF

Tags: html, json, pdf, extjs, export

My problem: Export my grid store to PDF.

Possible solution: I have looked at many post, many suggesting this [plugin from github](https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter)
`//problem is: This plugin uses Ext 3.0 and I need something in 4.1.`

Any other solution in ExtJS 4.1?

Answer (score 0):

The same one has been ported to ExtJS 4:

https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter

Comment: No, you'll need another component for this. I haven't seen one yet so far.